# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code when archive

Tags: swift, xcode

i have this error: Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code when I archive and I don't know what to do.

When I run on simulator I add `arm64` to `Excluded Architectures` in Build settings and it works. But when I try to archive it show me that error. So I tried to remove `arm64` to `Excluded Architectures`.

I tried lot of solutions of stackoverflow on several topics but any answer works.

I'm with Xcode 14.3 and here's the log: [image: Archive Log]

Here's my podfile:

```
platform :ios, '13.2'
def firebase_pods 
   pod 'FirebaseAnalytics'  
   pod 'FirebaseAuth'
   pod 'FirebaseFirestore'
   pod 'FirebaseStorage'
   pod 'GooglePlaces'
   pod 'FirebaseMessaging'
   pod 'MessageKit'
   pod 'GeoFire/Utils'  
end 

target 'My Team' do
use_frameworks!
   firebase_pods
   
end

post_install do |installer_representation|
    installer_representation.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'NO'
            config.build_settings['BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION'] = 'YES'
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While creating build in newer versions of xcode we all face same `rsync` error. so, perform given steps

1.search the frameworks.sh file inside pods folder

```
Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-{Project Name}/Pods-{Project Name}-frameworks.sh
```

2.search for source="$(readlink "${source}")" and replace it

```
#source="$(readlink "${source}")" // Comment this line
source="$(readlink -f "${source}")" // add this line or just edit above line with `-f`
```