# "No such module found" error but only when building my project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, module, cocoapods

I don't know what's happening with my Xcode project but everytime I build it I will get the error "No such module found" BUT when I go into the file that gets the error, after a few seconds the error will disappear as if it just found the module.

If I start typing to import a pod the autocomplete function can find them which proves that their there.

The missing module will change depending on which computer I'm using, on my M1 "ParseSwift" will go missing, on my IMac the module "Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK" will go missing. (again only when building.)

I only got this error after upgrading my xcode to 14.3 from 14.2, I've since uninstalled 14.3 and installed 14.2 again but I still get this error.

Currently I've tried the following:

1. Run the command `Pod deintegrate` via command line.
2. Delete "podfile.lock" and ".xcworkspace" file.
3. Delete "DerivedData" folder in Xcode folder.
4. Opened project using ".xcodeproj".
5. Clean project and try building it (fails obv) and close xcode.
6. Run `Pod Install`.
7. Launch project using ".xcworkspace" and try building it again but fails.

All the pods have been set to the same minimum IOS deployment of 12.0 alongside everything else in the project.

I also have another project that uses pods and it compiles fine with no errors.

My Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '12.0'

target 'MyProject' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyProject
  pod 'ParseSwift'
  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
  pod 'FirebaseAnalytics'
end

target 'MyWidgetExtension' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Widget
  pod 'ParseSwift'
end
```

Anyone have a solution to fix this? I can post more information if needed.

Comment: issue with pods path please try this solution it will definitely works. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75984932/16322682