# "The target has frameworks with conflicting names: OneSignal..." error when installing pods

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, onesignal

I've recently updated both Xcode & Cocoapods and now Im receiving this error each time I try to update the pods:

```
[!] The 'Pods-TestApp' target has frameworks with conflicting names: onesignal.xcframework, onesignalcore.xcframework, onesignalextension.xcframework, and onesignaloutcomes.xcframework.
```

I've tried navigating to the Pod folder and searching for two versions of the OneSignal pod but there weren't any. However, there are two folders: OneSignal & OneSignalXcFramework. I've read online that both libraries contain the same file names so I have a hunch that thats where the problem lies, but in that same thread, it was said that both could be used simultaneously. Here's my podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '16.0'

target 'TestApp' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  
  
      # Pods for TestApp
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'Firebase/Performance'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  pod 'Firebase/InAppMessaging'
  pod 'Kingfisher'
  pod 'GoogleSignIn'
  pod 'SideMenu'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'
  pod 'EmptyDataSet-Swift'
  pod 'SwiftSpinner'
  pod 'OneSignal'
  pod 'BSImagePicker'
  pod 'SkeletonView'
  pod 'BulletinBoard'
  
target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
  pod 'OneSignalXCFramework', '>= 3.0.0', '< 4.0'
end
  
  target 'TestAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'TestAppUITests' do
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

What can I do to resolve this issue?
Btw, I've tried de-integrating the pods & reinstalling them but that didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

You already given your questions answer.

```
target 'TestApp' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'OneSignalXCFramework', '>= 3.0.0', '< 4.0'

  target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
  
  target 'TestAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'TestAppUITests' do
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

after installation in case if you get `rsync` error.(This will occurs due to xcode update)

refer my other answer here.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75984932/16322682